# How to check for duplicate user input in Python/HTML form?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building a file storage system using the Google App Engine. Each user is able to login and create directories (Strings) for their accounts using a HTML form. I've been trying to not allow a user to add two directories with the same name but I cannot get it working.

Here is my form in HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
            Add a Directory: <input type="text" name="dir1"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Add Directory"/>
        </form>
        <br/>
        {% for i in directories %}
        Directory Name:{{ i.dir1 }}<br/>
        <br/>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="index" value="{{ loop.index - 1 }}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="button"/>
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
```

And here is my Python code in which I believe the check should be done:

```
 def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        action = self.request.get('button')
        if action == 'Add Directory':
            dir1 = self.request.get('dir1')
            user = users.get_current_user()
            myuser_key = ndb.Key('MyUser', user.user_id())
            myuser = myuser_key.get()
            new_directory = Directory(dir1=dir1)
            myuser.directories.append(new_directory)
            myuser.put()
            self.redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Python function, you could use ndb's [get_or_insert](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert) method which retrieves an entity if the specified key already exists or creates it if it doesn't.